# New build, CPU fan turns but getting 5 beeps

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, computer-building

I created a new build using the following new components:

1. [ASRok B360M HDV](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/B360M-HDV/index.asp)
2. Intel 9400f CPU. Note that this does not have on board graphics.
3. Crucial 8GB CT8G4DFS824A 8GB 2400 mhz

I also used up an old GTX 1070 that I had pulled from a dead eGPU box (not sure if the GPU is dead).

I am not able to get any display and have the following symptoms:

- RAM in slot 1 (gpu or no gpu): fans turning, no beep, cannot shut via power button (have to hold power button to shutdown), keyboard does not light up, hdd does not turn.
- No RAM (gpu or no gpu): fans turning, 3 long beeps repeating (have not tried keyboard, hdd).
- RAM in slot 2 (gpu or no gpu): fans turning, 5 short beeps once, can shut down via power, hdd powers on, keyboard lights up (caps and num-lock led works, can also restart using ctrl-alt-del)

EDIT: By "fans turning", I mean the CPU cooler fan, the case fan and the PSU fan. The GPU fan does not turn.

Any suggestions on what might be faulty?

I am led to believe that both the GPU and RAM slot 1 are faulty, and that getting a new GPU and using RAM slot 2 should work.

I wanted a second opinion before spending money on a new GPU.

(I may RMA the motherboard later on; for now I just want to see this boot properly).

Comment: [5 long beeps mean that the system couldn't recognize the graphics.](https://www.asrock.com/support/faq.asp?k=beep). [3 long beeps means no memory detected](https://www.asrock.com/support/faq.asp?k=beep). I would reseat the GPU and make sure the power is connected to the card properly. Does the GPU fans spin when you turn it on? When you say "fans spin" I'm not sure if you're talking about the case fan, heat sink fan, or GPU fan.

Comment: "I may RMA the motherboard later on; for now I just want to see this boot properly" - Before you go through a 3+ week RMA cycle.  You might want to figure out a way to verify if your GPU is the problem.

Comment: @DrZoo Sorry for the confusion.  By "fan spin", I mean the CPU fan and the case fan. The GPU fan has not spun till now.

Comment: [ASRock AB350M-HDV BIOS Beep Codes | DDR4Motherboard](https://ddr4motherboard.com/beepcodes/ASROCK-AB350M-HDV)

Comment: @DavidPostill My hunch is that the beep codes in that link are wrong.. I'll update everyone by tomorrow (ordered a cheap GPU and waiting).

Comment: If the GPU doesn't work, and the new one doesn't work, it could be a bad PCIe slot. If you have another computer, you could try the GPU in that one to see if it works. Otherwise an RMA will be your only choice since you only have one x16 slot.

Comment: Update: It was the GPU. I put in a new card and the system booted. One RAM slot doesn't work still. I suspect its due to bad placement/bent pins of the CPU. I might get around to checking it at some point in the future. For now, I can live with this as long as there are no other errors.